# What does "[]" represent in the following context?

Tags: ruby

Could someone please explain the difference between:

```
&.[](:key) 
.try(:[],:key)
.try(:key)
```

Specially what the "[]" represents in the first and second?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.[]` is a [method on the `Hash` object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D).

`x.[](:key)` calls the `[]` method with the `:key` argument and is equivalent to `x[:key]`

`&` is the safe navigation operator. `x&.[](:key)` would return `nil` if `x` is `nil` while `x.[](:key)` would cause an error.

```
x = {key: 123}

x[:key]
# => 123

x.[](:key)
# => 123
```

```
x = nil

x.[](:key)
# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

x&.[](:key)
# => nil
```

As far as the differences go, I don't believe there are any between the first and second, however `x.try(:key)` would try to call a `key` method on `x` and that would error out because it doesn't exist.

`x.try(:[], :key)` calls the `.[]` method with `:key` as an argument and is equivalent to what we saw above. As with the safe navigation operator, `try` returns `nil` if `x` is `nil`.

Comment: what about try(:key) vs try(:[], :key) ?

Comment: Edited that in and actually I had a small error in my initial answer because `.try(:key)` isn't equivalent to the other ones

Comment: thank you; I've been trying to google this for 20 minutes but the search engine seems to hate ruby symbols . . .

Comment: Ruby operators are all defined as methods on the objects so it allows for some non-intuitive invokations. For example instead of `1 + 2` you can call `1.+(2)` which invokes the `+` method on `1` with `2` as an argument.

Comment: Depending on the Rails version, [`x.try(:m)`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) will give you `nil` if `x.nil?` or `!x.respond_to?(:m)` where as [`x.try!(:m)`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try-21)` will give you `nil` if `x.nil?` and `NoMethodError` if `!x.nil? && !x.respond_to?(:m)`. So `try` does a little more than `&.` and `try!` is pretty much `&.`.

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding, `[]` is a special method similar to `fetch` on `Hash`:

```rb
hash = {a: 1}

hash.[](:a) # => 1
hash.fetch(:a) # => 1
```

[try](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try) is from Rails, could be used with syntax `Hash#try(:method, argument)`:

```rb
hash.try(:[], :a) # => 1
hash.try(:fetch, :a) # => 1
```